# Haskell: Where can I find the other operations from the finger tree paper?

Tags: sorting, haskell, sequence, finger-tree

The Finger Tree paper: http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html
is the basis for the Data.Sequence library: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-Sequence.html#g:10

But the library only seems to provide the functions for size-annotated finger trees.  It doesn't allow the client to provide other annotations to use.  In particular, the sort function returns another Seq, not a "SortSeq".

Is there an existing haskell implementation of FingerTrees which provide all the functionality described in the paper?

Comment: Never mind I found it, I've been googling "haskell sorted finger tree" and "haskell merge finger tree" and "haskell SortSeq", but it didn't occur to me to just google "haskell finger tree": http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree-0.0/docs/Data-FingerTree.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [fingertree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree) package (though I have not used it; only heard about it).